# Testing ApplicationListener with @SQL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

We have a spring bean doing some initialization stuff at bootup of a spring-boot application. To do so, the application registers a `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>`, which queries the database and acts upon the data.

To test this process, we have to inject testdata in the database. Our first try was to init the database with a test-specific `ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartedEvent>`. This works, however, the code looks rather nasty. The idea was to use the `@Sql` annotation instead to load the initial data.

This works not as expected, as the data is injected after the `ApplicationReadyEvent` has been published. I was unable to find means to change the phase during which the `@Sql` data is written to the database.

Is there a way to ensure, the data of `@Sql` is written prior to publishing the `ApplicationReadyEvent`? The test is currently otherwise annotated to run with `SpringRunner`, `@DataJpaTest` and with `@DirtiesContext`.

**Edit: Provide Code**

The ApplicationListener ist provided as this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    // Do someting with SQL-Data
  }
}
```

While the test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan
@Import(SomeTestConfig.class)
@DataJpaTest
//@SQL("/somedata.sql")
public class SomeTest {
  @Test
  public void test() {
    // Assert ApplicationListener has run
  }
}
```

With the test-config as follows:

```
@TestConfiguration
@Profile(ReplayTest.PROFILE_SOME_TEST)
class SomeTestConfig {
  @Bean
  public ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartedEvent> testSetupBean() {
    return new ApplicationListener<ApplicationStartedEvent>() {
      // Insert data within onApplicationEvent-Method
    };
  }
}
```

If I uncomment @SQL and comment-out the `@Import`, the testdata is visible from within the test itself but not from within the ApplicationListener.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `@Order` annotation. You can annotate your application listeners and your test with it. By default, this has lowest precedence. So you should provide higher precedence to your application listener and lowest to your test.

**Listener:**

```
@Override
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    System.out.println("...publishing application event");
}
```

**Test:**

```
@Test
@Sql(scripts = "test.sql")
@Order
public void test() {
   System.out.println("...loading data");
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work. I entered a syntactically incorrect SQL to test the ordering. Regardless of the order of the application-startup-listener and the test, the exception for the malformed SQL always occurs after the log output from the applicationlistener.

Comment: After some more evaluation: I think, the `TestexecutionListeners` are generally executed after the applicationcontext has been built. You seem to be able to order them but only among themselves, not among the generall execution cycle.

Comment: @Jonathan yes you are right, execution listeners are ordered among themselves. The above case works in order to first publish the event then execute the script. But not sure about your case, can you please provide some demo code.

Comment: I've put in code samples. Let me know, if you need more details.